# How to update a virtual Table with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this sql statement:

```
    SELECT 
     t0.col0,
     t0.col1,
     t2.col0,
     t2.col1,
     t1.col0,
     t1.col1,
     t3.col3,
     t3.col5,
     t1.col2
    FROM table0 t0
    INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t0.col0 = t1.col1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.col0 = t1.col0
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.col0 = t3.col1
    WHERE t1.col1 in (300, 301, 302, 302)
    AND t2.col5 like 'V-%'
    AND t3.delete = 'false'
```

this is working perfectly and shows a virtual table with the joined columns. So i try to directly update this Table like this way:

```
UPDATE T SET  T.col1 = 1, T.col2 = '01.01.2012'
FROM (
    SELECT 
     t0.col0,
     t0.col1,
     t2.col0,
     t2.col1,
     t1.col0,
     t1.col1,
     t3.col3,
     t3.col5,
     t1.col2
    FROM table0 t0
    INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t0.col0 = t1.col1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.col0 = t1.col0
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.col0 = t3.col1
    WHERE t1.col1 in (300, 301, 302, 302)
    AND t2.col5 like 'V-%'
    AND t3.delete = 'false'
) as T
```

without success... The only way to made it was to create a View and proceed update on it.

But can i update in one statement a virtual Table?

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to update a table, but the output of a select statement. It's not a virtual table, because the output goes nowhere.

I think you need something like this.

```
UPDATE T SET  t0.col0 = 1, t0.col1 = '01.01.2012'
    FROM table0 t0
    INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t0.col0 = t1.col1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.col0 = t1.col0
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.col0 = t3.col1
    WHERE t1.col1 in (300, 301, 302, 302)
    AND t2.col5 like 'V-%'
    AND t3.delete = 'false'
```